# WYSIWYG GUI builder (IDE) for JQuery or other JavaScript framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ide, wysiwyg

Are there any IDE's that allow building of web pages / user interface using javascript frameworks such as JQuery in a WYSIWYG manner?

For example, similar to how Dreamweaver allows you to build HTML pages or NetBeans allows you to graphically design Java applications, Flash Builder can graphically design flash applications.

I would think by now there is something that would let you plug in a javascript framework such as JQuery/JQueryUI or YUI or Prototype, etc. and for example drag in a JQueryUI styled button and position it and size it.   Throw on some JQuery fields or a datagrid?

Update:
  I have found a couple, so I am sure there must be more:

Sencha [Ext Designer](http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/) (commercial) -- supports the ext js framework, JQuery/Prototype and others.

[Maquetta](http://maqetta.org/) (open source) -- supports Dojo, some Jquery/YUI

[Wakanda](http://www.wakanda.org/)  (open source) -- very interesting, looks like their own JS framework.  May require the use of their back-end server for db, etc.?

Comment: I agree current IDE really really sucks ! Intellisense alone is just syntactic sugar it doesn't give any idea of what you're building.

Comment: What's with these dumb, clunky browser-based UI designers? (Maquetta) Developers too dumb or lazy to create standalone tools or Eclipse plugins these days? No matter I guess, it looks like it was "suspended" - not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 5):

For jQuery UI

[IxEdit is a JavaScript-based interaction design tool](http://www.ixedit.com/)

Comment: But it's 18 months later and that link still says "public beta". :(

Answer (score 4):

This works with jQuery Mobile only: [RIB](https://01.org/rib)

Answer (score 3):

Dreamweaver 5.5 allows you to access to all jQuery library features.

Answer (score 2):

There is Alpha Five as well, but this is only applicable if you are building a database application.  Wicked product.

Answer (score 2):

Wakanda v1 is out (beta phase is over).

Answer (score 0):

There's Google's [GWT Designer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/) (for GWT) and [Atlas](http://280atlas.com/what.php) (for Cappuccino).  Simpler, more Web-centric UI frameworks don't really lend themselves to a GUI designer, in my opinion, but some apps probably try to do it anyway.

Comment: both links are now dead. Please update.

Comment: …or you could do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Codiqa (https://codiqa.com/) a SAAS GUI builder, HTML5/jQuery UI.

Comment: Looks like this is mainly (?) for _mobile_ development. Haven't checked all details though.

Comment: If not, they're certainly catering to mobile heavily. WYSIWG is almost pointless with a tiny mobile UI. Enterprise PC desktop apps is where this is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

To create a GUI with jQuery UI widgets you can take a look here: http://umyproto.com.

Widgets are placed in the page by drag and drop, also you can write JavaScript for events, and finally you will have a bunch of HTML files which you can use in your code of an application.
it's really exciting, try it - you'll find a lot more for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience, but I couldn't provide full overview of the tool in the comment. It seems that 3 lines of text is enough to cover all essentials of a GUI builder.

Comment: Web-based only designer with a subscription? Worthless

Comment: It seems that link you provided is dead?

Answer (score -3):

Hey have you listen about linb visualjs. it works great with all server side languages with over 40 components with drag and drop and it is open source also with a good example book.
but you must know how to use JSON because it is totally based on JSON.

But good news is JSON is nothing but Javascript Array.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer makes much sense